# Setting display on iMac 5K Retina

Tags: display, resolution, mac

I'm currently running ubuntu within Parallels Desktop on my 27" iMac 5k Retina Display. Within the Display preferences in ubuntu, the resolution is "locked" as "Built-in Display" and the resolution is also "locked" at 800 X 600. I wanted to know how, if possible, I can change the resolution to take advantage of the most beneficial screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

That might not be a complete solution but may be it could help you since it would give you much better than 800x600. I have an IMac Retina. I run Ubuntu 14.04 inside Vmware Fusion. After enabling full retina display support in Fusion, I can set Ubuntu to support 2560x1600. In full screen mode, it is not as nice as the native retina with OSX but, it's still quiet nice. If I set it up to use about 1/4 of the screen, it really uses the  real "pixel" resolution. in full screen, it just makes everything bigger.  It's not perfect but it's quiet nice. From all my googling on the subject, it appears that it is the Linux drivers that are not meant to support such a large resolution/that many pixel. They are working on though.